# AndroidStudio opens previous project

Tags: android-studio, command-line

If I run androidstudio from project A folder, it still opens the last opened project instead of the project in the current directory.

Is it possible to force androidstudio to open the project from the current folder from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Settings-->Appearance & Behavior--> System Settings and uncheck

Reopen last project on startup

Hope this helps

Comment: Will try and update you. Btw, is there any way to force it via command line. Say opening studio from folder B should open project B.

Comment: It jsut opens the options to start/importproject,etc . I want it to open the current directory project.